# How to remove black screen between scenes in CCTransitionPageTurn?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I need to use CCTransitionPageTurn in my app between scenes.
When i run this transition, my running scene looks nice - it turns like page. 
but at the background i see black screen(during page turn animation), that is replaced later by new scene.
And i want to see new scene in the background(during animation), when i start this transition.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: Can you show some code? So we can see if you're setting things up correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, i found out the answer.
All works as it should, after i commented out this line

//director.projection = kCCDirectorProjection2D;

also i turned on depth buffer and changed depthformat.