# Cocos2D iPhone - removing the black screen between CCTransition

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am using cocos2d on my app. I am doing a transition to another scene using

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene: 
 [CCTransitionFadeDown transitionWithDuration:0.5f scene:otherScene]];
```

On the init part of this other scene, a menu is being built, using CCMenu. This is a full screen menu.

My problem is this: the transition happens to a black screen and then the menu appears. In other words, the transition is being done before the menu is rendered, so, I see an ugly black screen for 0.5 seconds and then, after the transition is done, I see the menu.

To make things clear imagine the first scene has a picture of a boat and the second scene a picture of a car. What I have now is the boat transitioning to black and then the car pops. I need the boat transition to the car.

how do I do that? thanks.

NOTE: I have found [this guy with the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282487/how-to-remove-black-screen-between-scenes-in-cctransitionpageturn), but I have tried that solution without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented a transition in my menu (same problem), call it 'fadeInView' by adding a black layer on top of everything in the init, with an opacity of 255, and in onEnter I run an action to fade the opacity to 0. as follows:

```
-(id) init {
    self=[super init];
    if(self){
        // do your stuff
        blackShroudLayer_=[CCLayerColor layerWithColor:ccc4(0, 0, 0, 255) width:K_SCREEN_WIDTH height:K_SCREEN_HEIGHT];
        [self addChild:blackShroudLayer_ z:500];
    }  
    return self;
}

-(void) onEnter{

    // need to [super onEnter] first to that we are running 

    [super onEnter];
    id sh = [CCFadeTo actionWithDuration:K_FADE_TIME opacity:0];
    id seq = [CCSequence actions:sh,[CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(onUnshroudComplete)], nil];
    [blackShroudLayer_ runAction:seq];
}

-(void) onUnshroudComplete{
     [blackShroudLayer_ removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
}
```

the constants and blackShroudLayer_ are defined in the class .h file.

Comment: I really don't get what you are doing here, but any way this is crashing for me (I think it crashing on the CCCallFunc part). Two questions: (1) how do you call this from the other scene? (I am using a simple replaceScene) ... (2) is there a way to use CCTransitionFadeDown instead of CCFade? (sorry, but I am a kind of newbie on Cocos2D). Thanks

Comment: misspelled the selector in the callfunc (fixed the code snippet). This would be the fadeIn of a CCTransitionFade (fades to black the current, then fades the next scene in).

Comment: @DigitalRobot : i have little experience with cocos2d scenes and transitions myself. The game's designers conceived all sorts of 'off the wall' scene transitions, and we could not use the pre-canned cocos2d transitions. So this is code is actually setup in the init, and when an object is added as a child to another cocos2d object, the 'onEnter' is automatically invoked by CCNode during the addChild process.  You can go here for a complete example of pretty much all coco's fades : http://www.pawapps.com/2011/07/30/tutorial-transitions-in-cocos2d/

Answer (score 2):

This is worth a try, if you are not already using it; it removes black flickers during scene loads. Run the following method before you switch scenes, in case it affects your issue (un-comment these lines and call the method directly):

```
- (void) removeStartupFlicker
{
    //
    // THIS CODE REMOVES THE STARTUP FLICKER
    //
    // Uncomment the following code if you Application only supports landscape mode
    //

    //  CC_ENABLE_DEFAULT_GL_STATES();
    //  CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
    //  CGSize size = [director winSize];
    //  CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Default.png"];
    //  sprite.position = ccp(size.width/2, size.height/2);
    //  sprite.rotation = -90;
    //  [sprite visit];
    //  [[director openGLView] swapBuffers];
    //  CC_ENABLE_DEFAULT_GL_STATES();

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I did that but the problem persists.